# Retrofit2 :- Do I need close connection if custom interceptor is added?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have read from documentation that if @streaming is used,We only need to close connection.

Do I need to close response anywhere in interceptor? Since I receive
OkHttpClient: A connection to http.. was leaked. Did you forget to close a response body?

```
internal class ApiResponseHeaderInterceptor(private val requestHelper: RequestHelper) : Interceptor {

    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val response = chain.proceed(chain.request())
        if (response.code == 200
            && !chain.request().url.toString().contains(BuildConfig.rootUrl)
        ) {
            if (requestHelper.verify(response.headers)
            ) {
                throw IOException("Exception")
            }
        }
        return response
    }

}
```

Comment: This interceptor in particular doesn't need to close the response body, you actually never opened it, but there might be somewhere else in your code that this is happening.